# Shouldn't an uninitialised var always be of type undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, initialization, standards, scope

I came upon a case where `var` behaves counter intuitively.

Here is an example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var toRun;

    if(i%2 !== 0) {
        toRun = {number:i};
    }

    console.log("toRun is", toRun);

    if ('undefined' != typeof toRun && 'undefined' != typeof toRun.number)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

The result when running with node js is:

```
toRun is undefined
toRun is { number: 1 }
toRun is { number: 1 }
toRun is { number: 3 }
toRun is { number: 3 }
toRun is { number: 5 }
toRun is { number: 5 }
toRun is { number: 7 }
toRun is { number: 7 }
toRun is { number: 9 }
```

I was expecting:

```
toRun is undefined
toRun is { number: 1 }
toRun is undefined
toRun is { number: 3 }
toRun is undefined
toRun is { number: 5 }
toRun is undefined
toRun is { number: 7 }
toRun is undefined
toRun is { number: 9 }
```

Is this normal behaviour in javascript?

Shouldn't toRun `var toRun` set `toRun` to `undefined` each time the code in the loop is executed?

```
node -v
v0.10.33
```

Comment: `var` statements are hoisted; assignments are not. You'll get what you want if you write `var toRun = undefined;`, for example, instead of just `var toRun;`.

Comment: @raina77ow :  
Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I wasn't aware js would move the initialisation of the variable to the start of the current function I was expecting it to do so at the block level. You should post this as an answer to get this question properly closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only functions create new scopes in JavaScript.  Declarations of variables are hoisted to the top of the innermost function.

```
function one() {
  var a;
  console.log(a);
  a = 1;
}

function two() {
  console.log(a);
  var a = 1;
}

function three() {
  console.log(a);
  for(var i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
    var a;
  }
}
```

These three functions have the same behavior - they print `undefined`.  Note that the declaration is hoisted, but not the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are normal behavior of the javascript. You're telling to browser to log only when it is undefined.

And you're really doing right way of checking 'undefined' as with typeof. typeof always returns string. So typeof is 'undefined' and in that condition browser will not log.

If you run the code without checking, then only you'll see the undefined vlaue for toRun.

Comment: The question is not about checking the typeof but about understanding why the var is not initialised to undefined each time the code is executed. @raina77ow has pointed the right reason.